# Delphi Seattle FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL not found

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-10-seattle, firedac

I am having an issue with Embarcadero Seattle. I'm new to Delphi and I am debugging someone else's code. I've had to setup on a different computer then the one that was used previously for this project.

[dcc32 Fatal Error] salesordermain.pas(14): F2613 Unit 'FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL' not found.

The TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink is not in the Tool Palete. I have reset it and  it does not appear. I have checked the FireDAC package and the component is not there. I've not had any luck so far trying to find out how to download/install the component.

Also, I have downloaded and installed Microsoft ODBC (msodbcsql.msi) and Microsoft Native Client (sqlncli.msi) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

See attached Photos of problem here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B58G8s8Edn7sNEo1MHFfRER2UEU

I am running Windows 7 64bit and networked MS SQL Server 2008 R2. Any assistance in helping me figure out how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Delphi SKU (Professional, Enterprise, Architect) are you using? Lower SKUs don't contain the same DBMS support as the higher versions.

Comment: See the [Delphi feature matrix (PDF)](https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-berlin-feature-matrix.pdf). Database support information starts at around page 17. You'll see that SQL Server support is only available in Enterprise+ SKUs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I'm using professional with the firedac add on pack.

Comment: Thank you, I will contact Embarcadero and verify and see what I need to upgrade to get it if indeed it isn't included. I'll update next week once I have a response.

Comment: @KenWhite, it is my understanding that the FireDAC Client/Server Pack for Delphi Professional should extend FireDAC to a level supported by the Enterprise edition. This should especially include MSSQL support. If it is not showing it might be a problem with the installation. See: https://www.embarcadero.com/app-development-tools-store/firedac-pack-for-delphi

Comment: @UweRaabe Years later... but I'm looking at that page, and it shows two FireDAC references - Pro supports local databases, while Enterprise supports remote databases. MSSQL is likely considered a "remote database".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to delete the FireDAC registration using the license manager(which is how I added it to begin with). Next I reran the Delphi Seattle installer.exe but selected "Upgrade" and entered in my FireDAC key, let the install run and BAM! The MSSQL part of FireDAC is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem and the solution was add FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL in the uses.