# Can't connect to SQL Server in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

I just installed the community version of Delphi, Delphi 10.3

I want to use FireDAC in stead of ADO,
so I want to test connections to `SQL Server` using `FireDac` but it is a complete disaster.

I dropped a `FDConnection` component on the form, and want to configure it to use `Sql Server`
There I notice I can choose from many `DriverNames` but not `MSSQL`
Why is that ?

So I tried the `FireDAC Explorer` but this has even more mysteries.
I add a new `Connection Definition` and there I can use `MSSQL`, but I cannot save this definition.
The `save` and `save as` button are disabled.
So I enter all the parameters I need, and yes, it opens my `SQL Server` database. I can see all tables, views, procedures... And I can even open a table to see the first 10 rows.
Great, if I could only save this definition...
Everytime I open the `FireDAC Explorer` my new definition is still there, but all parameters are not stored. I have to enter them all every time again.

But, no problem I think. I copy the parameters from the working definition and paste it in the `parameters` from the `FDConnection` on my form.
The parameters look like this

```
User_Name=xx
OSAuthent=No
Server=123.456.789.987\GTT
Database=DB_Test
DriverID=MSSQL
Name=DB_Test
```

Hm, interesting. Now it does show `MSSQL` as drivername. So let's set the `connection` property to true.
Now I get this error (allthough this is working fine in FireDAC Explorer with these parameters)

> [FireDAC][Phys]-300. Driver [MSSQL] is not registered. To register it,
> you can drop component [TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink] into your project.

Well alright, if that is all I need to do.
But, it seems I don't have the component `TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink`
I have others for all kind of databases, but not this one.

It seems there is something missing, but the errors don't give me much of a clue
So I am hoping there is someone here that understand the errors and can help me to fix this

**EDIT**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799553/delphi-seattle-firedac-phys-mssql-not-found) question here with an accepted answer, but I don't know how to use that answer. I have no clue how to use the `License manager` to register FireDAC

Comment: Firedac in the Community and Professional editions only supports local databases not connections to remote database servers like Microsoft SQL Server. See the chart on this page: https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/firedac

Comment: @Brian Really ? Damn did not see that. So what are my options to connect to SQL Server using this version ?

Comment: You can use the ADO* components on the dbGo tab.

Comment: @Brian Well I actually wanted to test something else then ADO, but I will have no choice so it seems. What I find very stupid about this is that I cannot demonstrate FireDAC to managment as alternative for ADO, and thus have not much change of convincing them to switch from VS to Delphi...

Comment: There is a trial of the Architect edition available but it is a bit short at 30 days to build/demonstrate much using it.

Comment: @Brian Exact the reason I went for the community version...

Comment: You may contact Embarcadero sales and negociate an extended period for the trial.

Comment: You may also use SQLite or any other local database to build your demo and demonstrate FireDAC use. Then when your demo is OK, you setup the trial version and then you have 30 days to modify your demo to use a remote SQL Server database.

Comment: @fpiette Now that is an idea that might actually work. Thank you

Comment: @GuidoG have you considered [dbExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DbExpress_Framework)? I've been using that for years (with [this driver](https://www.devart.com/dbx/sqlserver/)) to connect to SQLServer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not thought about that yet, I will give it a try. Thank you

Comment: Ado components work just fine, no need for FireSh*t...

Comment: Delphi is very constrained in DB connections. Instead use REST services and connect to any kind of DB-s in other (server side) apps use other technologies like Java Spring. In this case you separate your code from the concrete DB type. And you can test your app with mocks, there is no need for a real DB connection.